# Why database types aren't interface in GO

Tags: unit-testing, go

There is an emphasis on using interfaces instead of concrete types in order to make the code easier to test. I wonder though why this wasn't done for the types in the *sql* package like DB or Rows. In order to mock those dependencies I had to create my own interfaces so that I could write unit tests (not integration tests). Aren't DB facing code supposed to be tested that way?

Comment: Anybody can create interfaces for any type, in Go. It means there's zero need to declare an interface that you don't use. As you noticed, the fact there wasn't any pre-existing interface didn't prevent you from creating the ones you wanted.

Comment: Sure, I get that. But I come across many gophers emphasising the usage of interfaces upfront to make it easier for others to mock the concrete types. Maybe I'm overthinking this. Thanks.

Comment: @AmirKeibi: Interfaces make mocking a lot easier, true enough, but that doesn't mean package maintainers are supposed to create fully interface-based packages. There's a package out there that allows you to mock `database/sql` stuff quite easily: [go-sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock), maybe take a look at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing interfaces in your public API instead of concrete types increases the risk of breaking other peoples code when you add methods to the interface.

See for example [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File). If `os.File` was an interface it would be an interface with 17 public methods. Adding an 18th method would break everyone who defined their own types that implemented the `os.File` interface. In contrast, adding an 18th method to the current `os.File` struct won't break any methods taking an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) or any other interface that defines a subset of the methods of an `os.File`. It also won't break test code which mocks these `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` interfaces.

So expose an interface in your public API if you want other people to define their own implementations of them. Otherwise expose a concrete type and let people define their own interfaces implemented by your concrete type using only the subset of methods they need.